# Inhabitants of Vatican City would be referred to as ____

Tags: terminology, demonyms

Keep that blank clean. No religious flaming.

What I mean is this: inhabitants of America are *Americans*, inhabitants of Ohio are *Ohioans*, and inhabitants of Cincinnati are *Cincinnatians*. But what [demonym](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/demonym) would you use or have you seen used to refer to a resident of Vatican City? [This site](http://geography.about.com/library/weekly/aa030900a.htm) doesn't have one in its list, and the example for Sioux City, Iowa, found on [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demonym) would seem to suggest that maybe it's *Vatican Citian*, which just sounds awful.

Maybe it's one of those places that has never had a demonym. After all, "demon" does appear in the word…

Comment: My first impulse is "Vat", which on second thought sounds like a horrible experiment.

Comment: I would suggest Roman Catholics.

Comment: *"Catholics"* ::rimshot:: I'll be here all week.

Comment: @dmckee: *Holy chairs*.

Comment: Would anyone misunderstand if they were just refered to as *Vaticans*? And is it absolutely certain all of the few hundred that live there [permanently?] are (and must be) Catholics?

Comment: @FumbleFingers [Vatican citizenship](http://www.vatican.va/news_services/press/documentazione/documents/sp_ss_scv/informazione_generale/cittadini-vaticani_en.html) is given by appointment instead of birth. Nearly 75% of the population is clergy. The other quarter includes the Papal Swiss Guard, which I can nominally assume is Catholic, and "other laypersons" whose religious affiliation is unclear. Regardless, _Vatican_ sounds like a nice compromise.

Comment: Would this be different from residents of New York City or of Mexico City?

Comment: More of a comment than an answer, but I would surmise the reason there is no demonym for the Vatican City is that a demonym tends to imply nativeness more than just inhabitance. If I move to New York, I don’t normally automatically become a New Yorker—that’s (usually) reserved for people who are actually _from_ New York. And since no one is really _from_ the Vatican, there is no name for people from there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [CIA World Factbook](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2110.html?countryName=Holy%20See%20%28Vatican%20City%29&countryCode=vt&regionCode=eu&#vt), there is no official demonym for the Vatican City. I think I have seen *Citizen of the Holy See* used in print, although I can't remember where.

Comment: *Holy Seers*, perhaps? ;)

Comment: @gnovice, careful how you say that. It might sound like an expletive.

Comment: Demonym! What a _wonderful_ word!

Comment: How about *Vaticanos*?

Comment: @Benjol I believe the plural would be _Vaticani_ in Italian.

Comment: @HaL, yup, well spotted. Got mixed up with my (non-existant) Spanish :)

Comment: Latin would be more appropriate than Italian.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citt%C3%A0_del_Vaticano) says that the *nome degli abitanti* is *Vaticani*.

Answer (score 5):

I don't know the answer to this, but there are some sites with fairly comprehensive lists of countries and their demonyms, and they all list VC as 'none'.

[Here](http://www.geography-site.co.uk/pages/countries/demonyms.html) is one of those sites.

Also, [this](http://www.chacha.com/question/what-is-the-demonym-for-people-from-vatican-city-and-how-do-you-become-a-citizen) response seems fairly authoritative.

Comment: N.B.: Just realised my first link has only the same info as yours.

Answer (score 0):

Vaticaner would seem to be the most straight-forward and clear in English. People do live there in fact.

Comment: Do you have evidence that this is the demonym people use? There's evidence in other answers that there is no demonym actually in use, at least in English. I have seen *Vaticaner* in print but that was a German text.